# How to establish a Microsoft azure databricks delta tables connection using spring boot just like mysql,sql server

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

Hi I want to establish a connection with the Microsoft azure databricks delta table inside my spring boot application.I have the cluster url,username and the password(token) of the delta table from which I need to pull the data to my application. Kindly shed some light on this

Answer (score 3):

You can access cluster & underlying tables using the JDBC (see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/integrations/bi/jdbc-odbc-bi)).  You need to get the corresponding driver, and add it to your application, and then just use normal [JDBC API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/), like this:

```java
String jdbcConnectPassthroughCluster = "jdbc:spark://<server-hostname>:443/default;transportMode=http;ssl=1;httpPath=sql/protocolv1/o/0/xxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxx;AuthMech=3;UID=token;PWD=";

String PATH = "<personal token>"
String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.simba.spark.jdbc.Driver";
String DB_URL = jdbcConnectPassthroughCluster + PAT;

Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
System.out.println("Getting connection");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
System.out.println("Going to execute query");
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from table");
System.out.println("Query is executed");
int i = 0;
while(rs.next()) {
    System.out.println("Row " + i + "=" + rs.getLong(1));
    i++;
}
rs.close();
stmt.close();
conn.close();
```

Comment: HI Alex Thanks alot it worked but  I am actually trying to use Spring Data Jpa not the native query for querying the azure delta table so that we can avoid boiler plate codes.Can you provide any reference for that

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not Spring expert. I did expect that Spring is able to use any JDBC

Comment: Ooh ok no issues Thank you once again  Alex

Comment: I think we can still leverage the Spring Jdbc here